# SQL Server Windowing - 24 Hour Window

Tags: sql-server, window, windowing

I have the following data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [CustId] [int] NULL,
    [Spend] [money] NULL,
    [TimeOdSpent] [datetime] NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Test] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([CustId], [Spend], [TimeOdSpent], [ID]) 
VALUES (11, 400.0000, CAST(N'2016-10-27 10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([CustId], [Spend], [TimeOdSpent], [ID]) 
VALUES (11, 200.0000, CAST(N'2016-10-27 11:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 2)

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([CustId], [Spend], [TimeOdSpent], [ID]) 
VALUES (11, 400.0000, CAST(N'2016-10-28 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 3)

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([CustId], [Spend], [TimeOdSpent], [ID]) 
VALUES (11, 500.0000, CAST(N'2016-10-28 16:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 4)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Test] OFF
```

Expected Result should be like this

```
1   2016-10-27 11:00:00.000 600
2   2016-10-28 09:00:00.000 1000
3   2016-10-28 16:00:00.000 900
```

I want to find out the instances where the spend Totals > 500 within a 24 hour period. Being trying to write a windowing query without luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I was looking for. I used the Sales.SalesOrderHeader table from AdventureWorks Instead of my simple table above

```
  ;WITH cte1 as
(
select 
LAG(ShipDate) OVER(PARTITION By SAlesPersonId ORDER BY ShipDate) ShipDateBefore,ShipDate, SalesPersonID,SubTotal,CAST(ShipDate as Date) Date
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
where CAST(ShipDate as DATE)<'20080710' and SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
),cte2 as
(Select * ,DATEDIFF(ss,ShipDateBefore,ShipDate) as DiffinDays
from cte1
), cte3 as (
select * ,SUM(DiffinDays) OVER(Partition BY SalesPersonId ORDER BY ShipDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTime
from cte2
),cte4 as
(select 
*,ISNULL(CAST((RunningTime  / 86400.00) AS INT),0) Cycle
FROM cte3
)
SELECT 
SalesPersonID ,SUM(SubTotal)Total,MIN(ShipDate)DurationStart,MAX(ShipDate)DurationStart
from cte4

GROUP by SalesPersonID,Cycle 
Having SUM(SubTotal) > 100000.00
```

Comment: Idea is that, it cycles and groups by data entered within 24 hours. (Not mid-night to midnight). The downside is, the start of the 24 hour cycle is the first transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, Sm = sum(spend) over(partition by convert(date,timeofuse)) from #customer
) a
Where Sm > 500
```

Comment: That only considers a DATE boundary. i.e in this instance 2016-10-27 & 2016-10-28
What I need is this.
IDs 1 to 3 are within a 24 hour period, and Totals to 1000.
IDs 2 & 3 are within 24 hours and totals to 600
IDs  3 & 4 are within 24 hours and totals to 900

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: That is not what you asked in original question... But can you post your expected output in tabular format?

Comment: As I mentioned above.
 3 rows where total (>500) within the window 
p.s - the issue here is the 24 hour window, If this was by Date, then it would have been extremely simple.
Thanks Kannan, your help is much appreciated

Comment: Something like this......
1 2016-10-27 11:00:00.000 600
2 2016-10-28 09:00:00.000 1000
3 2016-10-28 16:00:00.000 900

Comment: You can modify your question and post expected output there... Still I am not clear